# How I can send data to the form and submit all to an email?

Tags: php

I am new to web so please help me. My problem is that I want some data to be sent with a form data to an email. I am using bootstrap, php for the

```html
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
    <div class="thumbnail">
         <div class="caption">
                 <p class="text-right"><span class="badge">35.00 JD</span><a class="btn btn-info btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ReserveModal" role="button">Request</a></p
             
             <h6 class="text-center"><b>XBEE 1MW - SERIES 1</b></h6>
             
             <p class="text-center"><button type="button" class="btn btn-circle"></button> <span class="badge" id="ho">10</span></p>
      
      </div>
      <img src="img/1-205x168%20(1).jpg"t="...">

    </div>
      </div>
```

I want when the user click on button "request" this text"XBEE 1MW - SERIES 1" to be sent with the data form to the same email.

[image: Contact form]

Comment: You're not using a form. How can you send data then?

Comment: Is it possible without using a form ? since I want to send this piece of information with other form information. I have only a contact form.